# Sending data from a Text Field to a Mutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitextfield

I have a textfield that I am trying to have the data sent to a Mutable Array when the user presses done. The only way this works is when I do `textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.textField.text, nil];` but then it rewrites the mutable array when the user taps adds another object. 
Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {

[self resignFirstResponder];

[textFieldArray addObject:self.textField.text];

NSLog(@"array: %@", textFieldArray);
}
```

This may be flagged as a duplicate question but I cannot find anything that solves my problem, Thanks for helping.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? The code appears to be correct.

Comment: @rmaddy it doesn't add the object to the array. When I log it it says `(null)`

Comment: Then you never initialize the array.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, just tried that but it just overwrites whatever is in the array, not add to the array.

Comment: Where are you initializing the array? It should be done once in the proper `init` method.

Comment: @rmaddy It does work, I had a typo in my code. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to `viewDidLoad:` method and it should work fine:

```
textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

You need to allocate and initialise this array,but not every time you adding new object in Array.

Comment: I'd put this in the proper `init...` method since it really has nothing to do with views.

Comment: @Greg My bad it does work, I had a typo in my code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you added this line I posted to viewDidLoad and it still override the data?

Comment: @Greg I put it in the viewDidLoad: method, i had a typo in my code but it works fine now, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {
     if(!textFieldArray)
     {
         textFieldArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.textField.text, nil];
     }
     else
     {
        [textFieldArray addObject:self.textField.text];
     }
}
```